# how to retrieve textfield value from tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview with 2 cells. Both cells have a textfield and a label. Textfield take the values of username/email address and password.

```
var emailAddress: String?
var password: String?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID) as! TextFieldCell

    cell.label.text = loginOptions[indexPath.row]
    cell.textField.placeholder = loginOptions[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        emailAddress = cell.textField.text!
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        password = cell.textField.text!
    }

    return cell
}
```

Here below is a function to check whether there is any text in the textbox and if not, display an alert controller suggesting to fill in all fields.

```
func signInButtonTapped() {

    if emailAddress!.isEmpty || password!.isEmpty {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "all fields are required to be filled in", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

How do I retrieve the textfield values from inside a cell to check whether they are empty or not? The code above does not work as the textfields always return empty. Although, hopefully it can be seen what I'm trying to acheive

Comment: The above code execute when the tableview is loaded. The textField is empty by that time. You should try use UITextFieldDelegate to observe the dynamic change in textField when it's been editing or done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your tableView has only one section. Then you can do this way

```
func signInButtonTapped() {
        let indexpathForEmail = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        let emailCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpathForEmail)! as TextFieldCell

        let indexpathForPass = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
        let passCell =  tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpathForPass)! as TextFieldCell

        if emailCell.textField.placeholder!.isEmpty || passCell.textField.placeholder!.isEmpty {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "all fields are required to be filled in", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

**step-1**

add delegate in your current class `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate
```

**step-2**

on your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` invoke the delegate to current field and add the tag also

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID) as! TextFieldCell
    
    cell.label.text = loginOptions[indexPath.row]
    cell.textField.placeholder = loginOptions[indexPath.row] 
     // add the following lines
     cell.textField.delegate = self
     cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
     
    
    return cell
}
```

**Step-3**

call the `UITextField Delegates`

```
 func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
print("TextField did end editing method called")

if !textField.text.isEmpty // check textfield contains value or not
 {
  if textField.tag == 0
  {
  emailAddress = textField.text!
  }
  else
  {
   password = textField.text!
  }
 }

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

textField.resignFirstResponder();
return true;
}

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {     
     if textField.tag == 0
  {
  emailAddress = ""
  }
  else
  {
   password = ""
  }
}
```

**Step-4**

call as useual your function if `emailAddress & password` is not contain values it through the error

```
  func signInButtonTapped() {
    
    if emailAddress!.isEmpty || password!.isEmpty {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "all fields are required to be filled in", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
else
  {
   // continue your work
  }
    
}
```

Comment: posting the same answer ! perfect solution upvoted !

Comment: @PranavGupte - tanx buddy

Comment: Seem to have a small problem.  If I type values into username and password, the values are set. When I delete the value and leave the space blank and setting a username/password, the same values are still set rather than an empty textfield.

Comment: @luke - check step -3 in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method , it surely works , if not we go for should char range method

Comment: Actually makes it worse off.  It seems to think the values are of the textfields are always empty regardless of input.  That being said, the other answer provided seems to work perfectly. Thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
  var tf = textField
   repeat {tf = superView.tf!} while !(tf is UITableViewCell)
    let cell = tf as! TextFieldCell
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

    //do further customization with indexPath
     switch indexPath.row {
       case 0: //assign value of row one to your data model,
       case 1: //assign value of row two to your data model
       default: break
    }
}
```